# Jquery masonry and infinite scroll combine

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, masonry

i do combine Jquery masonry and infinite scroll

http://jsfiddle.net/9tWw9/

```
<div class="col-main">
  <div class="col-left">
  </div>
   <div class="col-right">
   <div id="container">
     <div class="col" style="height:300px;">
     <p>1</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col2" style="height:320px;">
     <p>2</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col" style="height:360px;">
     <p>3</p>
     </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="page-nav">
  <a href="../pages/2.html"></a>
</div>
```

But it's not working

What is the matter

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some styles for the container and the infinitescroll js in the fiddle.

I guess this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/9tWw9/2/

```
#container { width: 100%; max-height: 2200px; overflow: auto;}
```

Comment: just copy it to my html file, and it show 1 column only, i need 3 column masonry brick with much row actually, sorry for missunderstanding @ciprian-coman